# Cloudant "case_clause" error with pouchdb when replicating

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, bigcouch, pouchdb

I am working with Pouchdb and Cloudant, and when my web app starts up it does a replication from Cloudant down to my pouchdb in the browser. I have an idea of how pouchdb works internally, and this is how I believe the process works (high level):

1. Replication starts
2. Gets a checkpoint doc from cloudant db (contains latest sequence number retrived from server, if not exists, assumes sequence # is 0, which is my case)
3. Grabs the changes from the changes freed starting at that sequence number (it grabs up to 25 changes)
4. Writes(or updates) the checkpoint doc back to cloudant server with the new sequence number (this way if a network error occurs, it can continue where it left off or for the next replication)
5. Repeats until no changes left
6. Replication complete

The problem is at step 4, that when pouch tries to write that doc to the cloudant server (for the first time), the server returns a 'case_clause' error. I am thinking the issue might be an invalid id sent to cloudant (cloudant doesn't accept ids of this format), because the id of the doc written to the server is `_local/799c37dfaefb3774a04f55c7f8cee947` (or other random numbers and characters at the end). I don't know if that is a valid doc id or not (for cloudant that is, because this is accurate for pouchdb), so I guess I am asking, is that the issue (unacceptable id for cloudant), or is there some other issue based on the error the cloudant server returns.

Here is the doc being written:

```
{
    _id: "_local/799c37dfaefb3774a04f55c7f8cee947",
    last_seq: "63"
}
```

Here is the full error output from Chrome debugger:

```
{
    error: "case_clause"
    reason: "{{case_clause,{ok,{error,[{{doc,>,
                                {338,
                                [>]},
                                {[{>,>}]},
                                [],false,[]},
                          {error,internal_server_error}}]}}},
    [{fabric,update_doc,3},{chttpd_db,'-update_doc/6-fun-0-',3}]}"
    stack: Array[4]
    0: "chttpd_db:update_doc/6"
    1: "chttpd:handle_request/1"
    2: "mochiweb_http:headers/5"
    3: "proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3"
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array[0]
    status: 500
}
```

Note: When I go into cloudant's Futon and manually enter the url for the checkpoint doc using its id, it does not exist.

Thanks

EDIT:

Header Info from the above request using Chrome debugger:

```
Request URL:http://lessontrek.toddbluhm.c9.io/db/ilintindingreseseldropec/_local%2F799c37dfaefb3774a04f55c7f8cee947
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview parsed
PUT /db/ilintindingreseseldropec/_local%2F799c37dfaefb3774a04f55c7f8cee947 HTTP/1.1
Host: lessontrek.toddbluhm.c9.io
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 111
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://lessontrek.toddbluhm.c9.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://lessontrek.toddbluhm.c9.io/app
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A8MVBFmbizTX4VNOqZNtIuxQI.TZ9yKRqNv0ePbTB%2FmSpJsncYszJ8qBSD5EWHzxQYIbg; AuthSession=(removed for security purposes, but valid); db_name=ilintindingreseseldropec; __utma=200306492.386329876.1368934655.1375164160.1375252679.55; __utmc=200306492; __utmz=200306492.1372711539.22.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); c9.live.proxy=(removed for security purposes, but valid)
Request Payloadview parsed
{"_id":"_local/799c37dfaefb3774a04f55c7f8cee947","last_seq":"63","_rev":"338-7db9750558e43e2076a3aa720a6de47b"}
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
x-powered-by: Express
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-couch-request-id: 7d2ca9fc
server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 07:29:23 GMT
content-type: application/json
cache-control: must-revalidate
content-encoding: gzip
transfer-encoding: chunked
via: 1.1 project-livec993c2dc8b8c.rhcloud.com (node-web-proxy/0.4)
X-C9-Server: proxy_subdomain_collab-bus2_01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudant, like CouchDB, expects all _local revs to begin "0-". pouchdb should not be generating rev values of this form. If you try this PUT against CouchDB you get the same stack trace.

Comment: Great, thanks. It's the presence of _rev, I think, which points to a bug in our _local doc handling. We'll get it fixed.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that! Thanks for pointing that out. If its a new doc, it shouldn't include _rev! I believe its also a bug in pouchdb too.

Comment: And, fyi, Cloudant, don't care about the _rev value anyway (for local docs). Supplying a _rev with non-0 seems to tickle a bug. For now, you can just drop _rev when updating local docs on cloudant.